# In a liquid template, how can I differentiate false from null?

Tags: null, liquid, falsy

In JavaScript, we can use strict equality (`===`, `!==`, etc.) to determine if something is truly `false` instead of just falsy. I have several nullable booleans in a model that is being passed into a liquid template, and the only mechanism I can come up with is to create a temporary variable that converts the boolean to a string by appending an empty string:

```
{% assign test = false %}
{% assign test = test | append: "" %}

{% case test %}
  {% when "true" %}
     TRUE
  {% when "false" %}
     FALSE
  {% else %}
     NULL
{% endcase %}
```

I know liquid doesn't have a complete standard, but this seems to be a problem across all implementations of liquid that I've seen. Is there another way to not have `null`/`nil` match the `false` case without converting it to a string?